# Stop voting system abuse without logging IP's?

Tags: php

Hypothetically speaking - Let's say i have a voting system, but users can essentially click the Like/dislike button non-stop. Raising/lowering the vote count by 100's in a few seconds by spam clicking.

I already introduced recaptcha to slow the process down, but what would you suggest as some form of mechanism to stop users from abusing the voting mechanism?

Rules: 
No Accounts (No Registration, just anonymous voting)
No IP Logging

What would the best method to fix this be?

Thanks!

Comment: The only other method that I can think of is the use of cookies but this can be overridden.

Comment: browser fingerprinting?

Comment: Either @RamRaider 's suggestion or have user accounts and a one vote per account configuration. It would still be anonymous since you can have users register without an email, just username and password. This would slow it down quite a lot.

Comment: Related: [How to prevent cheating (extra votes) in online contests?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10601/how-to-prevent-cheating-extra-votes-in-online-contests)